# MarkLogic / NoSQL / NewSQL & Web Application Frameworks - Architecture for new Application

Tags: web-applications, marklogic, web-frameworks, nosql

I want to develop an app that is easily scalable ( to millions of users ultimately )  from the start and can accommodate standard tables with dimensions of Data per user but conform to some standard data formats ( like XSD ). I have looked at MarkLogic and it looks very fast and scalable and would support the XML type data that I want to use ( with maybe some JSON for various parts ) .

My questions:

1) What is a Good Web Application Framework that would scale with it.  I lean towards ASP.NET MVC C# but that is because I am familiar with it. I looked at Node.js but seems like there would be some scaling issues.

2) Is MarkLogic a good choice? I'm new to NoSQL / NewSQL but I understand the concepts. What else is out there that would scale very well?

Been thinking about using Amazon AWS

I have a background in Regular relational DB + Web Applications ( SQL Server / MySQL / Oracle ASP.NET MVC etc ) + XML + C# etc etc

- done a bit with Kendo UI but found it a bit tiresome with lack of docs combined with a few bugs that cost me FAR too much time.

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work for MarkLogic as the Developer Community Manager.

On your first question, MarkLogic provides supported wrappers for the [MarkLogic REST API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev) for [Java](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java) and [Node.js](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev). For other languages, you can either make HTTP calls directly to the REST API, or use one of the community-driven wrappers as a starting point ([you mentioned .Net](http://developer.marklogic.com/labs/mldotnet)). I'm not enough of an expert at Node to talk about its ability to scale, so I'll leave that part to others. The purpose of the REST API is to provide simple access regardless of the language you are working with.

For your second question, is MarkLogic a good choice for an application with XML and JSON data that will need to scale -- yes.

- MarkLogic scales out very well, with [many customers fielding large deployments](http://www.marklogic.com/customers/). The shared-nothing architecture means that you can grow your application with commodity hardware, rather than needing progressively more expensive machines. (See [Scalability Considerations](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/scalability))
- MarkLogic supports [ACID transactions](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions), so your data will be safe.
- MarkLogic supports, but does not require, the [use of schemas](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/loading_schemas#chapter).
- You mentioned possibly deploying on AWS. MarkLogic works well there, giving you the ability to scale your application up and down by adding and removing servers. MarkLogic will balance data among the available servers for you. See the [MarkLogic Server on Amazon EC2 Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2).
- I'm not familiar with Kendo UI, but I think you'll find MarkLogic [well documented](http://docs.marklogic.com/). We provide API documentation, guides, tutorials, and other content to support developers.

Comment: @Martin if you want to kick the MarkLogic tires, it's worth noting that you can download and try it free as a developer.  And since you're interested in AWS, you might be interested to look at a promotion to try that free: http://www.marklogic.com/faststart  --disclosure, I'm an Engineer at MarkLogic

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure, I also work for MarkLogic (engineering core team).
In addition to Daves comments, MarkLogic also supports a Native .NET interface, XCC.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xcc
This API has Java and .NET implementations which are equivalent.

However, unlike the API's Dave mentioned, XCC is a lower level API then the REST based APIS so typically requires more coding and knowledge of MarkLogic.
However it is native .NET library with a very good mapping to C# and other .NET data types.  I'd compare it to writing software in C++ vs Ruby or Python.

Other alternatives are to code at the HTTP level using any HTTP library in any language and does not require any marklogic specific client libraries.
( .NET has quite good HTTP).   This approach takes a bit more work and understanding to get going as you need to write server side code to implement most tasks, but with Version 8 MarkLogic supports both XQuery and JavaScript as server side code for HTTP connections.

Being the lowest level API (HTTP), similar to other software stacks, 
there is a tradeoff of ease of development vs more precise control.
This can be a significant factor for some applications where executing
custom code directly on the server can do things that are inefficient or 
very difficult with pure client side code.

Many people end up using a combination of APIs as they learn what work 
better for their use case and experience.  In Version 8 *all* of the APIs can be access on the same port concurrently, from the the same or different clients in different languages and threads.    You may find this useful if you have developers with different skill levels, language familiarity, to integrate into existing applications without having to leave that language or to write parts of your app in server side code as you find it useful.  Since the server itself is entirely agnostic of what API and language is used you can keep the same data model and documents and evolve your application over time without needing to change the data itself.

While all these choices seem confusing, what it ultimately means is that you dont need to worry that much about your initial language or API choice, or whether a future project or developer will prefer something different.  That lets you get on with actually writing your app.   Pick a language you like and write a quick demo app and see if you like it, if not try another or mix & match.  As you scale to larger capacity you may find the server side languages helpful for some operations without having to migrate the entire app - or maybe you move some parts to the browser or a middle tier, add a caching layer or expand to a different cluster and storage topology - all independant of your existing code.